# Why does println! work only for arrays with a length less than 33?

Tags: arrays, rust, println

In Rust, this works:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [0; 32];
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [0; 33];
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[{integer}; 33]: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:22
  |
3 |     println!("{:?}", a);
  |                      ^ the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `[{integer}; 33]`
  |
  = note: `[{integer}; 33]` cannot be formatted using `:?`; if it is defined in your crate, add `#[derive(Debug)]` or manually implement it
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`
```

I assume that the `std::fmt::Debug` function somehow detects types up to a length of 32 elements, but then drops it's detection. Or why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Starting with Rust 1.47 (2020-10-08), [this is no longer true](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/10/08/Rust-1.47.html#traits-on-larger-arrays)!** Almost all traits are now implemented for arrays of arbitrary length. So **you can now print arrays of length 33**!

Old answer below for reference.

---

Sadly, Rust does not support integers as generic parameters yet. Therefore it's not easy to implement a trait (like `Debug`) for every array `[T; N]`. Currently, the standard library uses a macro to easily implement the trait for all length up to 32.

To output the array, you can easily convert it to a slice (`&[T]`) this way:

```
let a = [0; 33];
println!("{:?}", &a[..]);
```

By the way: Normally you can obtain a slice from an array by simply prefixing `&`, but `println` arguments work a bit different, so you need to add the full range index `[..]`.

---

The situation is likely to improve in the future. [RFC 2000: Const Generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2000-const-generics.md) has already been accepted and mostly implemented in the compiler. It would allow for `impl` blocks generic over the length of the array. You can track the status of implementation and stabilization on [the corresponding tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580).

Comment: [Just a link to the macro implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b30d8969e86fa2c9dd3b8e2e28ddda2202331f0f/src/libcore/array.rs#L112) - I guess, it may be helpful.