# How to use another array's length to initialize an array in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust

I want to initialize an array whose length is equal to another array's length:

```
fn foo(array: &[i32]) {
    let mut sum = [0; array.len()];
}
```

It will make an error:

```
error[E0080]: constant evaluation error
  --> test.rs:22:18
   |
22 |    let mut sum = [0; array.len()];
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ unsupported constant expr
```

I think I must use this `len()` argument... How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually taking the length of a slice, not an array. Array lengths must be known at compile time. `array.len()`, being the length of a slice, is potentially derived from runtime input, and as such cannot be used as an array length. You can create a vector instead. For example:

```
use std::iter::repeat;

fn foo(slice: &[i32]){
    let mut sum: Vec<i32> = repeat(0).take(slice.len()).collect();
    // ......
}
```

Comment: It could be written easier as `vec![0; slice.len()]`.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question asked:

> How to use another array's length to initialize an array in Rust?

As of Rust 1.51, you can write generic code like:

```rust
fn foo<const N: usize>(array: [u8; N]) -> [u8; N] {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

See [Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423) for further details.

The solution for previous versions of Rust involves a combination of traits and macros. This has the distinct disadvantage of being limited to a set of types. This is discussed further in questions like [Why does println! work only for arrays with a length less than 33?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33036859/155423)

---

Showcasing the shorter, more idiomatic version of the `Vec`-based code:

```rust
fn foo(slice: &[i32]) {
    let mut sum = vec![0; slice.len()];
}
```